# CMD Script Errorlevel Misbehavior with IF statement

Tags: cmd, errorlevel

Expected outcome of the following script: PERMPING if user presses P, or PINGLOOP if user presses T. However, no matter what the user presses, the script echos **both**. Any idea what gives?

```
CHOICE /C:PT /N /M "Ping permanently (P) or temporarily (T) (%pingTimes% times)?"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO PERMPING
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 ECHO PINGLOOP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not acurately reporting the results of your code. The code you have posted should print both if P is pressed, and only print PINGLOOP if T is pressed. The behavior is due to how the IF ERRORLEVEL statement works, as is explained by the help. To get help on any command, simply type `HELP commandName` or `commandName /?` from a command prompt. In your case, you could use `IF /?` to see the following

```
Performs conditional processing in batch programs.

IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
...
  ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                    returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                    specified.
...
```

You have 2 choices to make your code work:

Test the conditions in decreasing numerical order and use the ELSE clause

```
CHOICE /C:PT /N /M "Ping permanently (P) or temporarily (T) (%pingTimes% times)?"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
  ECHO PINGLOOP
) ELSE IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO PERMPING
)
```

or use `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==N`

```
CHOICE /C:PT /N /M "Ping permanently (P) or temporarily (T) (%pingTimes% times)?"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 ECHO PERMPING
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 ECHO PINGLOOP
```

Comment: My simple mistake had my poor mind boggled! Thanks for the fix, dbenham!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159327/1126551) if [command extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are turned on you can also use:

[if %errorlevel% equ 1 echo PERMPING](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

[if %errorlevel% equ 2 echo PINGLOOP](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Thanks for the additional tip!